# Why does getClass().getName() work on a module class that is not open?

Tags: java, reflection, module, java-9

I have two Java 9 modules, a server, and a handler.  The server loads HTTP handlers with the ServiceLoader (code below).

Why does the `o.getClass().getName()` in this snippet work?  Is it because `provides` opens the handler class up to reflection? Does getClass().getName() not use reflection?  Does Java somehow always map an interface to the underlying class instance (and thus to the class) without needing reflection?

server module code:

```
    ServiceLoader
      .load(HTTPHandlerWithContext.class)
      .stream()
      .map(ServiceLoader.Provider::get)
      .forEach(o -> {
        System.out.printf(
          "registering route %s to %s%n",
          o.getContext(),
          o.getClass().getName()
        );
        server.createContext(o.getContext(), o);
      });
```

handler module-info:

```
module com.example.helloworld {
  requires com.example.tinyjhttpd;
  requires jdk.httpserver;
  provides com.example.tinyjhttpd.HTTPHandlerWithContext
    with com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld;
}
```

What I think is the relevant snippet from Class.java was not enough to make it clear to me:

```
    // Cache the name to reduce the number of calls into the VM.
    // This field would be set by VM itself during initClassName call.
    private transient String name;
    private native String initClassName();
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen with `o.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: @Holger Raise an error since the module containing the class I am calling getName() on did not allow reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification does not define Reflection (and hence, the impact of `opens` or the lack thereof) in detail but rather [refers to the API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4):

> [...] This specification constrains the behavior of such classes and interfaces, but does not provide a complete specification for them. The reader is referred to the Java SE Platform API documentation.
>
> Consequently, this specification does not describe reflection in any detail. Many linguistic constructs have analogs in the Core Reflection API (`java.lang.reflect`) and the Language Model API (`javax.lang.model`), but these are generally not discussed here.

The Java SE Platform API documentation specifies when an `IllegalAccessException` can be thrown, e.g. on invocations of [`Field.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) or [`Method.invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object...)).

Neither [`Object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) nor [`Class.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) have been specified to potentially throw an `IllegalAccessException`.

This is consistent with the runtime behavior of Java before the module system introduction. Just the rules regarding when an access is granted or not became more complex.

The impact of being able to query the name of a class is rather low compared to accessing the internal data or invoking non-API methods.

Comment: What about `Class.getAnnotationsByType(...)`? It does not declare to throw an IllegalAccessException, however the API docs of [`RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) state that this retention policy allows the annotation to "be read reflectively".

Comment: @SebastianS what is your question, exactly? `getAnnotationsByType` does not declare to throw IllegalAccessException and it will never throw IllegalAccessException. When the annotation does not have the `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`, it will never be returned by `getAnnotationsByType`, just the way it works since Java 5.

Comment: The question is if it counts as reflection. Your explanation says **no** (because of the missing exception). But the linked docs explicitly say **it is** reflection.

Comment: @SebastianS I never said that whether “it counts as reflection” determines whether it throws an exception. Where did you see that in the answer? I said, *reflection is not covered by the JLS*, the JLS even directs its readers to the API specification regarding reflection, explicitly. So, in case of reflection, the API specification is the only authoritative source. If the API specification says that a reflection method can not fail with an `IllegalAccessException`, it can not fail with that exception. No contradiction to the JLS, because the JLS says “look at the API specification”.